# ASP.NET MVC Show message before redirects if success

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-pages, identity

Here's my web api on account controller using identity that can change the password wit validation using data annotations

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ChangePassword(string email, string returnUrl)
    {
        return email == null || returnUrl == null ? View("Error") : View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _changePasswordCommand.ChangePassword(model);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                ViewBag.IsSuccess = true;
                ModelState.Clear();
                return Redirect(model.returnUrl);
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }
        return View(model) ;
    }
```

then in my div razor views

```
        <form class="change-password-form" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ChangePassword" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input id="email-hidden" asp-for="Email" type="hidden" />
            <input id="return-url" asp-for="ReturnUrl" type="hidden" />
            <div class="form-group change-password">
                @if (ViewBag.IsSuccess == true)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center">Successfully Changed Password!</div>
                }
                <label asp-for="CurrentPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" asp-for="CurrentPassword">
                <span asp-validation-for="CurrentPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group change-password">
                <label asp-for="NewPassword" class="control-label">New password</label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="newPassword" asp-for="NewPassword" onkeyup="isGood(this.value)">
                <span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group change-password">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmNewPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmNewPassword" class="form-control" type="password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmNewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="change-password-footer">
                <button id="btn-cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cancel">
                    CANCEL
                </button>
                <button id="btn-save" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save" disabled>
                    SAVE
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I want to be able to show the successfully changed password message before it redirects problem is it always redirect to account/changepassword after submit

Answer (score 0):

You can write `if` condition outside the `form` tag, like this

```
@if (ViewBag.IsSuccess == true)
{
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center">Successfully 
     Changed Password!
 </div>
}

<form class="change-password-form" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ChangePassword" method="post">
@*your code*@
</form>
```

Or remove `method="post"` then try

Answer (score 0):

look at this place in your account controller.

```
...
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    ViewBag.IsSuccess = true;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return Redirect(model.returnUrl);
}
...
```

Instead of the re-direct, use "return View(model);". then you can redirect the page ajax, (testing if the ViewBag.IsSuccess == true and model.returnUrl != null) you in the account controller, you will instead have.

```
...
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    ViewBag.IsSuccess = true;
    ModelState.Clear();
    //return Redirect(model.returnUrl);
    return View(model);
}
...
```

With this, the success alert would show. Then have a javascript method onload, test if success is true and the the return is not null. something like this (in the view)

```
...
@{
    bool isSuccess = ViewBag.IsSuccess;
    string rUrl = model.returnUrl;
}

...

<script>
   function redirect(isSuccess, returnUrl)
   {
       //use ajax to redirect;
   }
   redirect(@isSuccess, @rUrl);
</script>
```